# How to trigger or bring up android search box by tapping an image?

Tags: android, search

Please forgive me my english is not very good and i'm new to android programming.

I have a picture/image in my main activity of my dictionary app and I would like to bring up the "android search box" in that activity when you 'tap' the image instead of using the menu key to search is this possible to do and how?

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

"To invoke search from your Activity, call onSearchRequested()."

Comment: Thanks very much but I still can't do it!

Answer (score 1):

Use your activity's `startSearch()` method, which allows you to specify application or global search.  (Which is what it sounds like you're looking for.)

The default behavior of `onSearchRequested()` is to call `startSearch()` with the `globalSearch` argument set `false`, restricting search to just your application's data.